# how to ask user input for list of strings

Tags: string, scala, user-input

I wanna know how to ask user input for a string. For example:

when user input is asked "lruud" is entered

```
Enter letters: lruud
```

and I want it the return should be:

```
Left
right 
up
up 
down
```

left = l, right = r, etc.

So basically it should return the result in the order the letters are entered.

The code below is what I have tried where al() is move left, ar() is move right etc

```
def move(s: String) {
  if(s == "l"){
    al()
  }else if(s == "r"){
    ar()
  }else if(s == "u"){
    au()
  }else if(s == "d"){
    ad()
  }  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us code that doesn't work so that we can better focus our suggestions.

Comment: def move(s: String) {

    if(s == "l"){
      al()
    }else if(s == "r"){
      ar()
    }else if(s == "u"){
      au()
    }else if(s == "d"){
      ad()
    }  
  }

thats the code

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. As you can see, SO comments make for terrible code formatting.

Comment: sorry I am new here, havent gotten comfortable with how to use everything.
But I edited my question its much clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in a string from standard input using

```
val s = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
```

Scala [implicitly](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/strings.html) considers `String` to be a Scala collection, in particular an `IndexedSeq` which means you can call standard collections methods on it such as `map` to transform it. For example

```
def move(s: Char): String = {
  if (s == 'l') "left"
  else if (s == 'r') "right"
  else if (s == 'u') "up"
  else if (s == 'd') "down"
  else throw new RuntimeException("Bad input")
}

"lruud".map(move)
// res4: IndexedSeq[String] = ArraySeq(left, right, up, up, down)
```

Mapping over a `String` reads each `Char` in the string and passes it to the `move` method for transformation.

Comment: thank you that code works. But now what if instead of the letter "l" being equal to "left" it is equal to a function for example al(). So what I want is if the letter "l" is entered it does the function corresponding to that letter in this case if "l" then does the function al()

Comment: I tried replacing "left" with al() but gives an error saying that required string found unit

Comment: @SurajOdedra Then you need to change the return type of `move` from `String` to `Unit` that is `def move(s: Char): Unit`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to go about this.

```
val action :Map[Char,String] =
  Map('d'->"down",'l'->"left",'r'->"right",'u'->"up")
    .withDefault(c => s"$c?")

val moves :Seq[String] =
  io.StdIn.readLine("Enter letters: ").map(c =>action(c.toLower))

println("\ndirections:\n" + moves.mkString("  ","\n  ",""))
```

testing:

```
Enter letters: lLdRbu

directions:
  left
  left
  down
  right
  b?
  up
```